# HTTPURLConnection write command works only with read

Tags: java, amazon-s3, http-headers, httpurlconnection

I am writing a file into AWS S3 bucket using HTTPURLConnection. This connection's outputstream-write command works only if it is followed by getInputStream or getResponseCode. Please help me to understand this. Is it required to read responseCode?

```
       URL endpointUrl = new URL("muURL");
       HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) endpointUrl.openConnection();
   connection.setRequestMethod("PUT");
                
    connection.setRequestProperty("Authorization", authorization);
    connection.setRequestProperty("x-amz-content-sha256", hashPayload);
    connection.setRequestProperty("X-Amz-Date", myDate);
    connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type","application/octet-stream");
    connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Length",contentLen);
    //connection.setRequestProperty("Accept","*/*");

    connection.setUseCaches(false);
    //connection.setDoInput(true);
    connection.setDoOutput(true);

    DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream(connection.getOutputStream());
            wr.writeBytes(payload);

    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();

    // If I comment this line which gets responseCode , then file is not written in S3.
            builder.append(connection.getResponseCode());
                
    wr.flush();
    wr.close();
    connection.disconnect();
```

I am expecting this code to work without getResponseCode line.

Comment: My hunch is that you need to close the connection's OutputStream, but I see you do indeed call `wr.close()` was that included in the code when you don't call `getResponseCode()` ?  Refer to this Tutorial: https://www.baeldung.com/httpurlconnection-post which uses the try-with-resources construct for safer programming

Comment: Yes, wr.close() was included always, I tried commenting getResponseCode() line only. I will check that tutorial. Thanks for your reply.